# Separate tables based on business goals

Tags: sql, database, database-design, architecture

Is it worth to split tables bases solely on the business goal?

**NOTE: The tables all have identical columns.**

### 1. One table

One `orders` table, with a `orderType` column to differentiate them.

### 2. Two tables

TWO tables called `sales_orders` and `purchase_orders`.

### 3. Many tables

How about even more tables like `sales_quotes`, `sales_orders`, `sales_backorders`, `purchase_requisitions`, `purchase_orders`...

---

I believe approach 3 is pushing it too far, while approach 1 is too much mental load to keep filtering 2 very distinct business goals.

Approach 2 seems like just enough separation, but not sure if it will haunt me later.

PS: I am aware it's opinion based, let me have this one.

Comment: One table, 2 views (if you really need to separate the types)

Comment: How different are the orders, how many columns are different between them? I'd expect sales and purchases to be so different that you shouldn't combine them, but quotes, orders and backorders could be combined.

Comment: Do you know the access patterns?

Comment: Think the *life-cycle* (the flow of control) of the corresponding entities and the users/roles involved as a guiding factor: one and the same life-cycle => one entity, different life-cycles => different entities...

Comment: @NickW The views suggestion is a great one. Can you please tell me why you prefer one table?

Comment: @Charlieface The orders are identical i.e. there are no differing columns between them. The only separation is a mental one i.e. the business case.

Comment: @PeterCsala No, what do you mean by it?

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio Can you please tell me what you mean by life-cycle?

Comment: @Ivan  In general, to *entities* may be associated a state-transition diagram to represent what informally may be called their "life-cycle", which is the most basic component of what more precisely in SE is called (a representation of) the "flow of control".  Correspondingly, in the entity one would find a 'State' attribute to keep track of the current state.  For example (and just for example, as concrete solutions depend on requirements), an Order might be: Received, TakenChargeOf, Rejected, Cancelled, Shipping, Fulfilled, Payed, Refunded, Backshipped.

Comment: @Ivan `what do you mean by it?` Do you know how they will be queried? Together, separately? Do you want to join tables if they are stored in multiple tables? Do want to index them based on the same columns? Do you have same constraints for the same columns in different tables? etc...

Comment: @Ivan I prefer one table as it is the simplest solution to build, populate and maintain. If it works for you, why make life more complicated than it needs to be? Plus all this discussion is a technical one not a business one - the business doesn't care how their data is stored, just how it is presented to them. Unless you have a technical reason for creating 2 tables, go with the simplest solution

Comment: @NickW  <<all this discussion is a technical one>>  The *life-cycle of an entity* is a business (functional) requirement, not a technical one.  Then of course an implementation may boil down to a single table if that is enough, but that is the technical decision.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio ok, so we can agree to disagree. Which is one of the reasons why this forum doesn’t allow questions which require an opinion based answer :)

Comment: @NickW  Well, that this question is opinion-based is itself an opinion :), and I'd think my answer implies that a technical answer here, at least a basic one, is at least possible.  But, of course, disagreement is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it worth to split tables bases solely on the business goal?

In my opinion and experience, the short answer is yes.  Indeed, not only it is worth it, *business (functional) requirements* are in fact the main if not the only guiding factor, certainly to the conceptual data model.  Technical considerations, including plain normalization, should come down the line, and anyway be taken with care: the more the implementation diverges from the conceptual model (even just in terms of levels of abstraction!), the less it becomes understandable *and* maintainable (and extensible, etc.).  ("Avoid premature optimization: already at design level.")

More specifically, for **a concrete criterion**: consider the *life-cycles* of your *entities* (as represented by state-transition diagrams, including the users/roles involved): one and the same life-cycle => same entity, different life-cycles => different entities.

(In general, to entities may be associated a state-transition diagram to represent what informally may be called their "life-cycle", which is the most basic component of what in SE is called (a representation of) the "flow of control". Correspondingly, in the entity one would find a 'State' attribute to keep track of the current state. For example (and just for example, as concrete solutions depend on requirements), an Order might be: Received, TakenChargeOf, Rejected, Cancelled, Shipping, Fulfilled, Payed, Refunded, Backshipped.)